# Chart.js: Widen hover distance for points

Tags: chart.js

Is there a Chart.js option for increasing the distance from a point at which its tooltip becomes active?

By default, a point is "active" and tooltips are displayed when the mouse is hovering directly over a point. I'd like to give the user a little more area around points to make them "active."

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this, by setting `pointHitRadius` property to a value of hit distance, for your dataset, like so ...

```
...
datasets: [{
      pointHitRadius: 20,
      ...
}]
...
```

**Working example**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Rating',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(209, 230, 245, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(56, 163, 236, 1)',
         borderWidth: 1,
         pointHitRadius: 20 //set as you wish
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could I ask you to use ordinary characters from UTF-8? The stylised charset may not work on all mobile devices, and in any case there's no particular need to try to use a different "font". Unfortunately people would add their own stylesheets if they could here, and sparkly animated backgrounds too, so it is good they cannot `:-)`.